# Почему не удается обновить QLabel на виджете?

Tags: qt5, pyqt5

Господа программисты, подскажите пожалуйста в чем ошибка, QLabel не обновляет текст на виджете. Вроде бы я уже сделал простейший пример, а не работает. Текст стоит тот с которым была инициализация и все.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QTime
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGraphicsView
from usvika.experiments.qt_example.widget_view import Ui_Widget
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets



class Ui_Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi()



    def setupUi(self):
        self.graphicsView = QGraphicsView(self)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.graphicsView)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.addStretch(1)
        self.label_x = QtWidgets.QLabel('abc', self)
        self.label_y = QtWidgets.QLabel('def', self)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_x)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_y)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)

        self.setLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        self.setWindowTitle('Quarry Map')
        self.resize(792, 806)
        self.show()



class mywindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mywindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Widget()
        self.ui.setupUi()


    def updateTime(self):
        time = QTime.currentTime().toString()
        print("Time: " + time)
        self.ui.label_x.setText(time)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    application = mywindow()

    timer = QTimer()
    timer.timeout.connect(application.updateTime)
    timer.start(1000)

    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score -1):

Сам нашел ответ. :-)
Надо было вот так делать ...  с  def retranslateUi() и прочим зоопарком...

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QTime
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGraphicsView
from usvika.experiments.qt_example.widget_view import Ui_Widget
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore


class Ui_Widget(object):
    def setupUi(self, Widget):
        Widget.setObjectName("MapWindow")
        self.graphicsView = QGraphicsView(Widget)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.graphicsView)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.addStretch(1)
        self.label_x = QtWidgets.QLabel('abc', Widget)
        self.label_y = QtWidgets.QLabel('def', Widget)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_x)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_y)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)

        Widget.setLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        Widget.setWindowTitle('Quarry Map')
        Widget.resize(792, 806)

        self.retranslateUi(Widget)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Widget)

    def retranslateUi(self, Widget):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Widget.setWindowTitle(_translate("Widget", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_x.setText(_translate("Widget", "TextLabel"))

class mywindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Widget()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)


    def updateTime(self):
        time = QTime.currentTime().toString()
        print("Time: " + time)
        self.ui.label_x.setText(time)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    wig = mywindow()


    timer = QTimer()
    timer.timeout.connect(wig.updateTime)
    timer.start(1000)

    wig.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```